# how to get data from a dataset and pass it to a list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was trying to get the data from this data object team and I am passing it to a list. when I am running the program instead of Data I am getting System.Data.DataRowCollection. please let me know whats the wrong thing that i am doing here ?

```
public ActionResult notifications()
    {
        List<notifications> Teamwon = Getsports();
        return View(Teamwon);
    }
    public List<notifications> Getsports()
    {
        string lname;
        string lvenue;
        string ldate;
        string lteam1;
        string lteam2;
        string leaname = "0";
        string leavenue = "0";
        string leadate = "0";
        string wteam = "0";

        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=DESKTOP-59SGH72\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sport;Trusted_Connection=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter usersport = new SqlDataAdapter("select sports_details_id from users_sports_following where user_id ='" + Session["userid"] + "'", sqlConnection1);
        DataSet sportds = new DataSet();
        usersport.Fill(sportds);
        int count = sportds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        List<string[]> leaguelist = new List<string[]>();
         List<string[]> teamlist = new List<string[]>();
        while (count != 0)
        {
            Int16 id = Convert.ToInt16(sportds.Tables[0].Rows[count-1]["sports_details_id"].ToString());

           using (SqlDataAdapter leagueDetails = new SqlDataAdapter("select league_name, league_details_venue,league_details_date,sports_details_id1,sports_details_id2 from leagues, league_details where sports_details_id1 in ('" + id + "') or sports_details_id2 in ('" + id + "')", sqlConnection1))
            {
                DataSet leagues = new DataSet(); 
                leagueDetails.Fill(leagues).ToString();

                lname = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_name"].ToString();
                lvenue = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_venue"].ToString();
                ldate = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_date"].ToString();
                lteam1 = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sports_details_id1"].ToString();
                lteam2 = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sports_details_id2"].ToString();

                string[] fields = new string[5];
                fields[0] = lname;
                fields[1] = lvenue;
                fields[2] = ldate;
                fields[3] = lteam1;
                fields[4] = lteam2;
                leaguelist.Add(fields);
            } 
            count = count - 1;
        }           
        List<notifications> notificationlist = new List<notifications>();
        foreach (string[] fields in leaguelist)
        {
             leaname = fields[0];
             leavenue = fields[1];
             leadate = fields[2];
            var id1 = fields[3];
            var id2 = fields[4];

            SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Remember;server=DESKTOP-59SGH72\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=sport");
            SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter("team", sqlConnection2);
            ////mention the adaptor that it needs to ru stored procedure
            ds.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id1", id1);
            ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id2", id2);

            //fill the dataset
            DataSet da = new DataSet();
            ds.Fill(da).ToString();
            string team = da.Tables[0].Rows.ToString();
            notificationlist.Add( new notifications
            {
                leaguename = leaname,
                leaguevenue = leavenue,
                date = leadate,
                teamwon = team
            });
        }
        return notificationlist;
    }
}
```

}

please help me with how to get the data from team object..!! i am sending the notification list to my view. I am getting all the data except the data from team object

Comment: `da.Tables[0].Rows.ToString()` => certainly `ToString` returns `System.Data.DataRowCollection` type instead of row content. What do you want with the table rows?

Comment: @`Testsuya YAmamoto i just have some names in that table and i am trying to put them in a list with the team object.

Comment: @`Testsuya YAmamoto I just used ToString() because i thought the data from the row would be converted in to a string. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I think you need to use `da.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex][columnindex].ToString()` instead of `da.Tables[0].Rows.ToString()`. Provide [mcve] code to see your effort.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto using a stored procedure and team will have output values. ds.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id1", id1);
 ds.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sports_details_id2", id2);
 DataSet da = new DataSet();
 ds.Fill(da).ToString();
string team = da.Tables[0].Rows.ToString();
notificationlist.Add( new Notification
                { leaguename = leaname,
                    leaguevenue = leavenue,
                    date = leadate,
                    teamwon = team
                });
            }

Comment: Is that `leaname`, `leavenue` & `leadate` also assigned from the table row values? I see what you're trying to do now, by using `for` loop to iterate the table & get all values from there (will provide further explanation).

Comment: @tetsuya yamamoto yes, they are from a different loop but i am getting those values correctly its just this value i am getting that system.data.datarowcollection instead of data

Comment: Can you provide table structure & other relevant codes by editing your question? I almost figured out what you want but needs details how you assign `team` value.

Comment: @tetsuya yamamoto structure of which table did you want..??

Comment: Of course the table data you're passing to the `team` value... which retrieved from `SqlDataReader` as `DataSet.Tables`. I want to know the column location and how many rows you want to pass as string.

Comment: @tetsuya yamamoto i am passing the data from team to a attribute in notification list and i will be sending it to my view

Comment: @tetsuya yamamoto Hey i am sorry for the late reply i have edited my question and posted the code that i am working with, please have a look at it and let me know what to do..

Answer (score 1):

This `ToString()` assignment in `da.Tables[0].Rows.ToString();` certainly returns `System.Data.DataRowCollection` since the method returns type of [`DataTable.Rows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of row values. The proper usage to retrieve row values should be like this:

```
// both 'rowIndex' and 'columnIndex' are int values (must be positive & start from 0)
da.Tables[0].Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex].ToString();
```

Or using column name for column part:

```
da.Tables[0].Rows[rowIndex]["columnName"].ToString();
```

Either using `for` or `foreach` loop with counter from `ds.Tables[0].Rows`, assign both row and column index to pull values from stored rows like this example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
{
    // other stuff

    // assumed you want to pull "teamwon" column
    string team = da.Tables[0].Rows[i]["teamwon"].ToString();

    // add values to the list
    notificationlist.Add(new Notification { leaguename = leaname, leaguevenue = leavenue, date = leadate, teamwon = team });

    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: my view code <table class="table">
    <tr>
 <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.leaguename)</th>
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.leaguevenue)</th>
<th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date)</th>
<th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.teamwon) </th>
</tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{     
 <tr>
<td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.leaguename)</td>
<td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.leaguevenue)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.date)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.teamwon)</td>
 </tr>
  }
</table>